# VMware Esxi 6.7 - Guest OS Password

Tags: c#, vmware, esxi

I am trying to upgrade my Virtualization module for VMware developed in C# from older version to VMware 6.7. How to set Guest OS Password/hostName/IP with vmware Esxi 6.7? with older versions, I was using VIX tools(VmRun.exe with command "runProgramInGuest"). What is the alternate for VMware 6.7? 
I already googled it alot and unable to find some understandable solution. Please guide me in right direction.
Any help will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

VIX was deprecated as of 6.5 and moved into the vSphere Web Services API:

> For vSphere, the VIX API was deprecated in 2012, as announced in the VIX 1.11 Release Notes. VIX 1.14 was the last supported release for vSphere. VIX is no longer supported with in 6.5 and VMware Tools 10.1.0 and later.

In the vSphere Web Services API, you're looking for the startProgramInGuest method that's part of the GuestProcessManager object: https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/fe08899f-1eec-4d8d-b3bc-a6664c168c2c/7fdf97a1-4c0d-4be0-9d43-2ceebbc174d9/doc/vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please guide me further? For older versions, I have added reference of "Vim25Service2005" and "Vim25Service2005.XmlSerializers". (from vix tools installation folder). What steps I should take to use "vSphere Web Services API" now ? Which references I should add in my project for latest version? Can you please share some documentation's link about how to use VM Operations in a project ? any link for examples etc ?

Comment: as VIX API was deprecated, I cannot use "VMRun.exe" and I am facing difficulties to use "startProgramInGuest". Is there any documentation about how to use these operations with examples?

Comment: There's a Ruby example in the opening issue: https://github.com/vmware/rbvmomi/issues/111